# CSS: div positions dislocated

Tags: css

On my computer I have it perfectly looking, it is a 17"

I went to see my web under development on www.hrcprojectconsulting.com on another computer, an old screen of 1080 x 600 i think

and the right panel has dislocated itself from its position and taken the middle container

I conceived it as One main container that wraps, a left container, a center container and a right container. I positioned the main container centered with margin: 0 auto; and it all looked good. Then I had to had the banner, the blue stripe that you will see:

This is my blueprint for all pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "<?php echo base_url() ?>css/style.css" />
<script type ="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/1.8.js"></script>




    <div id = "contenedor_principal">

    main wrapper
    <div id = "left_container">
    content for left panel
    </div>


     <div id="container-center"><!-- 1 -->
```

content for the center panel

```
     </div> <!-- end of container center 1 -->

    <div id = "right_container">

    and for the right panel
    </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "<?php echo base_url() ?>css/main_style.css" />        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "<?php echo base_url() ?>css/webform.css" />
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/1.8.js"></script>



</head>

<div id="header" class = "header"><h1 class="header">Real Estate Worldwide</h1>


<body>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#contenedor_principal
{

    background:orange;
    width:1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}   



    div.panel,p.flip
{
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background:#FFFFFF;

}

#container-center{

  width:635px; /*** Set to = center col width ***/
  height:500px;

  font-size:8px;
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
    left:485px;
    top:80px;

/* \*/
  margin-left:-1px;
/* Hidden from IE-mac */
}


#left_container{
  width:200px; /*** Set to = center col width ***/

  height:500px;
  float:right;
  margin-right:0px;
  font-size:8px;
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
    left:275px;
    top:80px;

/* \*/
  margin-left:-1px;
/* Hidden from IE-mac */
}

#right_container{
  width:202px; /*** Set to = center col width ***/
  margin-left:0px;
  height:600px;
  float:right;
  font-size:8px;
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
  right:260px;
  background:url('../assets/uploads/miweb/bg_body.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
  top:80px;

/* \*/
  margin-left:-1px;
/* Hidden from IE-mac */

}



#header {

    float:inherit;
    background: url("../jq185/css/start/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_75_2191c0_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #2191C0;
    font-family: 'trebuchet ms',geneva,arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1050px;
    height:75px;
    h2 {color:#ffffff;}


}
```

Than can anyway be seen live on my web like I said. I am using 1660 x 900 and 17" but it should be viewable on any resolution and screen.

Any clue as to why it went all upside down?

thank you

Comment: live link? And why is your header outside the body?

Comment: because I did it wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout you are using is wrong. no need to use `position: absolute` for every div and then set the top and left.

Instead of that follow the below structure.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="left_content"></div>
                <div id="middle_content"></div>
                <div id="right_content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container  {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#header {
    background: blue;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#left_content {
    float: left;
    width:150px;
    background: red;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
#middle_content {
    float: left;
    width:620px;
    background: green;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
#right_content {
    float: right;
    width:150px;
    background: red;
    min-height: 600px;
}​
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/X4Hwm/)
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your css, you clearly coded everything in order it comes correctly *only* on your screen.

In particular what is going wrong is your `#right_container` in which you say `float:right` and than `right:260px`.

A *quick* (but bad) solution to your css would be to put `float:left` instead of `float:right` and define the number of pixels from the left `left:1190px` (1190 is approximate)

A *better* solution would be **learn properly css and play with it afterwards**!

Comment: I understand. Well first of all, since your center-container is with a fixed `width`, you cannot use `float:right` on the right-container, since you have no idea how far from the right border you'll have your center-container.

Comment: I see, then, can I just leave it to some flexible width? how does that go?